# How to define the click action in a push notification for Progressive Web App (PWA)?

Tags: java, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I have installed my Progressive Web App on my Android mobile phone. When I send a push notification to this app (with my user token), a bell appears in the top bar. When I pull down the bar, I see the notification box with the title and text. When I tap this box, the window closes, but the app in the background does not come to the foreground! What do I have to do so that my installed app, which is in the background, comes to the foreground?

I would also like to prevent this notification from asking whether the URL should be opened in the browser! This has already happened. The default browser should not be opened, but the already installed app should be brought to the foreground.

I send the message via the Firebase SDK with a Java app on my server.  Here I can only specify a title and text for the notification message, but no click action. Or can I?

My method for creating the notification

```
public static Message.Builder createMessage(String title, String body, String user_token) {
        Notification notification = Notification.builder().setTitle(title).setBody(body).build();
                
        Message.Builder message = Message.builder().setNotification(notification).setToken(user_token);
        
        return message;
    }
```

Here is the url to the document I used for orientation [FirebaseMessagingSnippet](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/b4ab5903fb337b6023e331feb317f0866872c439/src/test/java/com/google/firebase/snippets/FirebaseMessagingSnippets.java)

When I tap on the notification box, I expect the pwa to be brought to the foreground.